# LCD USB communication

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb

[image: A usb/serial LCD]

This is on Arch Linux.

I connected it and using dmesg I got the output:

```
[   78.637285] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   78.953772] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[   79.110482] cdc_acm 5-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

So using /dev/ttyACM0 I was able to send characters to it using `echo -en "t" > /dev/ttyACM0`, but almost straight away it displayed 'AT' which through trawling the internet is an attention command sent to modems. After a few seconds random text appeared and it became unresponsive. Is this due to the OS thinking this is a different device than it is? Is there a way to manually tell the system to leave this device alone and let it be communicated to through ascii only?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What makes you think that writing `t` to the device should do anything? What model of panel is it? As far as the kernel is concerned, it's just a serial line.

Comment: "t" was an example, it works by just sending ascii of what you want to display. The problem is that the kernal is communicating to it using the wrong protocol. Is this because it misinterpreted what this serial device is? This is the technical information page https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/usb-plus-serial-backpack.pdf

Comment: It's using the AT90USB162 chip

Comment: You may need to set some serial port parameters (e.g. speed, parity, etc.). Try a program like minicom or microcom. It isn't the wrong protocol (there's only one, it's a serial port) but it may be wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a reply to the original question, this can be fixed by using minicom, running:

```
sudo minicom -s
```

And setting the device to be used, saving the setup to dfl.

Thank you very much! Hopfully this will be useful for anyone else trying to debug this issue.

Comment: Or another very capable serial terminal program `picocom` (which I almost like better than minicom for better UTF-8 character handling). All distros have picocom available and connecting is simply `picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyACM0` (or whatever baud rate you want). Another serial program is `tio` -- much the same as the other two, or you can just use `screen` as well.